# Android Trouble with database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am selecting contacts from contact book,displaying them on ListView and storing them in SQLite database.Lets suppose I have selected 3 contacts i.e contact A,contact B,contact C. Now when I restart the emulator, its showing me contact A,contact B,contact B,contact B,contact B,contact C......on the ListView Please help. What am I doing wrong.

MySQLHelp.java

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userdetails";
      public static final String TABLE_NAME_MSG = "usermessage";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "NUMBER";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
      public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID_MSG = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_MSG = "message";
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userInformation.db";

      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
      private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "create table "
          + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
          + " text not null,"+COLUMN_NUMBER+"  text not null,"+COLUMN_TYPE+" text not null);";
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_MSG = "create table "
              + TABLE_NAME_MSG + "(" + COLUMN_ID_MSG
              + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_MSG    + " text not null);";
      private static final String DATABASE_INSERT_MSG = "insert into  "
              + TABLE_NAME_MSG + "(" + COLUMN_MSG+") VALUES('enter your message');";


      public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_MSG);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT_MSG);

      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
      }

      public long insertContact(ContactItems contItem) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME, contItem.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER, contItem.getNumber());
            values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, contItem.getType());

            // insert row
            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            // assigning tags to todo
            /*for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
                createTodoTag(todo_id, tag_id);
            }*/

            return result;
        }


      public ArrayList<ContactItems> getAllContacts() {
          ArrayList<ContactItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactItems>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ContactItems conItems = new ContactItems();
                    conItems.setName(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME))));
                    conItems.setNumber((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NUMBER))));
                    conItems.setType(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TYPE))));

                    // adding to todo list
                    contactList.add(conItems);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            return contactList;
        }

    public void updateMsg(String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // String selectQuery = "update  " + TABLE_NAME_MSG+" set "+COLUMN_MSG+" = '"+msg+"' where "+COLUMN_ID_MSG+" = 1";
          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_MSG, msg);
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         db.update(TABLE_NAME_MSG, values, null, null);

    }
    public String getMsg() {
        String message ="";
          String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MSG;

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MSG));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(LOG, "message = "+message);
        return message;

    }

    public int removeData(String number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           //db.drawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
          return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NUMBER + "='" + number+"'", null) ;

    }

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        //message.setFocusable(false);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);
        dbHelper= new MySQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
        selectedContactList = dbHelper.getAllContacts();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                alert);
        spinner.setAdapter(adp);
        final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                String selectedItem = alert[position];
                message.setText(selectedItem);

                // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to
                // EditText
                //message.setText(pref.getString("AutoSave", ""));
                // to bring cursor to front
                message.setSelection(message.getText().length());

                message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // saving text after it is changed by the user
                        pref.edit().putString("AutoSave", s.toString())
                                .commit();
                        dbHelper.updateMsg( s.toString());

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

         @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.i("data", uri.toString());
            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri,
                                    new String[] {
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                    null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        final ContactItems item = new ContactItems(
                                c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2));
                        item.setName(c.getString(0));
                        item.setNumber(c.getString(1));
                        item.setType(c.getInt(2));
                        selectedContactList.add(item);

                        Set<ContactItems> s = new TreeSet<ContactItems>(
                                new Comparator<ContactItems>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public int compare(ContactItems o1,
                                            ContactItems o2) {
                                        // for preventing duplicacy of contacts
                                        // and calling toast
                                        if (o1.number.equals(o2.number)) {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Selected Number Already Exists",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {


                                        }
                                        return o1.getNumber().compareTo(
                                                o2.getNumber());

                                    }
                                });

                        s.addAll(selectedContactList);
                        selectedContactList.clear();
                        selectedContactList.addAll(s);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // save the task list to preference
dbHelper.insertContact(item);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: The problem may be on your Adapter. Paste the code you are using for the adapter

Comment: `COLUMN_ID` and `COLUMN_ID_MSG` is same name

Comment: @antoniom please have a look

Comment: @antoniom the duplicacy of the number is because of dbHelper.insertContact(item) . Can you suggest me where to place this code.

Comment: @bhanukaushik dbHelper.insertContact must be inserted **AFTER** comparing

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `s` is a TreeSet of unique `ContactItems` you have to enter the following code, probably after you `selectedContactList.addAll(s);`

```
for (ContactItems item : s) {
     dbHelper.insertContact(item);
}
```

Notice that on your `Comparator` you must probably override the `equals` method

Comment: please check what i have done ... i just simply pasted the code below and its working fine